# OpenProcess function with two dwDesiredAccess

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Based on microsoft documentation, dwDesiredAccess parameter can be one or more of the process access rights.

I want to pass two different dwDesiredAccess (PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION and PROCESS_TERMINATE) when I call openProcess function. Can anyone show me how to call the function?

```
HANDLE hprocess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, 0, static_cast<DWORD>(proc.th32ProcessID));
```

Please note that the above code is for one access right.

Comment: On an unrelated note, assuming `proc.th32ProcessID` is coming from `PROCESSENTRY32` then it is already a `DWORD` and does not need to be `static_cast`'ed to a `DWORD`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like most Win32 functions where you can set multiple parameters in a single argument, you need to simply bitwise **OR** in the parameters together:

```
HANDLE hprocess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION|PROCESS_TERMINATE, 0, static_cast<DWORD>(proc.th32ProcessID));
```